# django celery daemon does work: it can't create pid file

Tags: celery, daemon, django-celery, celerybeat, celeryd

I can't init mi celeryd and celerybeat service, I used the same code on another enviroment (configuring everything from the start) but here don't work. I think this was by permissions but I could'nt run it. please help me.

this is my celery conf on settings.py

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = ‘djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend’
CELERY_BROKER_URL = ‘amqp://localhost’
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = [‘json’]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = ‘json’
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = ‘json’
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER =  ‘djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler’
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE  # ‘America/Lima’
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE= {}
```

this is my file /etc/init.d/celeryd

```
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd
```

then I use

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/celeryd
sudo chown admin1:admin1 /etc/init.d/celeryd
```

and I created /etc/default/celeryd

```
CELERY_BIN="/home/admin1/Env/tos/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="tos"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/admin1/webapps/tos/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
CELERYD_USER="admin1"
CELERYD_GROUP="admin1"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

export SECRET_KEY="foobar"
```

for celerybeat I create a file on /etc/init.d/celerybeat
 with:

```
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celerybeat
```

and start service like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat start
```

and I have this error:

```
sudo: imposible resolver el anfitrión SIO
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
celery multi v3.1.25 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
    > celery@SIO-PRODUCION: OK
ERROR: Pidfile (celery.pid) already exists.
Seems we're already running? (pid: 30198)
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 515: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid: not found
```

I also I got it when check it with :

```
sudo C_FAKEFORK=1 sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
some data .....


starting nodes...
ERROR: Pidfile (celery.pid) already exists.
Seems we're already running? (pid: 30198)
    > celery@SIO-PRODUCION: * Child terminated with errorcode 73
FAILED
+ --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 515: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid: not found
+ --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 517: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log: not found
+ --loglevel=INFO
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 519: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --loglevel=INFO: not found
+ --app=tos
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 521: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --app=tos: not found
+ --time-limit=300 --concurrency=8
/etc/init.d/celeryd: 523: /etc/init.d/celeryd: --time-limit=300: not found
+ exit 0
```

Comment: From your logs it is not clear if pid file already exists or if '%n' is not replaced with your node name. You can always try to start celery like this and play with options: 'python -m celery worker -A your_celery_app_name --pidfile=/tmp/test.pid --uid=<uid of your admin user> --gid=<gid of your admin user>' (check python -m celery worker --help for options.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i resolved her so:

```
rm -f /webapps/celery.pid && /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

You can try do this. Before running celery clean up pid-files through ampersand by gluing commands.

Answer (score 0):

Other way, create a django command

```
import shlex
import subprocess

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        kill_worker_cmd = 'pkill -9 celery'
        subprocess.call(shlex.split(kill_worker_cmd))
```

Call it before you start, or just

```
pkill -9 celery
```